# NetworkManager + VPN: How to set default route through VPN?

Tags: vpn, routing, networkmanager

Since a dist-upgrade yesterday evening (running Debian Sid), NetworkManager appears to have stopped overwriting the default route set up through my local router once I connect to a VPN. Google indicates that this is intended, as most people apparently *don't* want to clobber their routes like that. I, however, would. How can I restore the old behavior?

Details: I have the VPN connection set up to be automatically established once the connection to my local net is there. It appears to be irrelevant if I configure the interfaces through DHCP or manually since at that point, a default route through my local router is needed.

Once the connection is finished, that default route persists, bypassing the VPN; thus, all connections made through it get blocked by my firewall which allows the physical interface for local traffic (almost) exclusively.

Once I issue `ip route del default`, the route through the VPN appears - I don't have to add it manually. This has to be repeated after every connection attempt. I tried messing with the ipv4.route-metric but apparently it's just ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in NetworkManager v1.0.10-1. Nasty - I'm lucky I have that firewall, otherwise my traffic would have been exposed since the default route is preserved. For now, downgrading, upgrading to a newer version (not yet in the Debian repos) or a custom dispatcher script fixes it.